# How to integrate $x \ln(x)$ over density of $x$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, density-function

Say there is a variable $x$ with density function $f(x)$. Also, $x$ has domain $[0, \bar{x}]$, where $\bar{x}$ is some real valued upper bound. Is it possible to find a tractable solution to

$$
\int_0^{\bar{x}} x \ln(x) f(x) dx
$$

My attempt:

Noting that $f(x)$ can be rewritten $\frac{dF}{dx}$, where $F(\bar{x})$ is the cumulative distribution function corresponding to $f(x)$, I rewrite the integral as

$$
\int_0^{\bar{x}} x \ln(x) \frac{dF}{dx} dx = \int_0^{\bar{x}} x \ln(x) dF
$$

Then, integration by parts gives

$$
\int_0^{\bar{x}} x \ln(x) dF = x \ln(x) F(\bar{x})-\int_0^{\bar{x}} F(\bar{x}) d(x \ln(x))
$$

But here I get lost as it seems to me that $F(\bar{x})$ should be factored out of the integral on the RHS, which would then result in the whole equation evaluating to $0$.

Comment: It should be $F(x)$ in the second integral and it should be $\overline x\ln\overline x$ outside. That's all there is to it.

Comment: I can't even understand the question. What do you mean by "find"? Even if we replace $x\ln x$ by just $x$, there's nothing we can do (other than give it a [name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value)).

Comment: @Gae.S. I don't understand. Could you please expand in an answer? You get 100 bounty points if your answer is correct.

Comment: Oh, Jesus, now I feel bad. I was just pointing out a mistake: given $F'=f$, the correct identity should be $$\int_0^{\overline x} f(x)g(x)\,dx= F(\overline x)g(\overline x)-F(0)g(0)-\int^{\overline x}_0 F(x)g'(x)\,dx$$ whereas you mixed $x$ with $\overline x$. I don't think there is a reasonable answer to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Until $f(x)$ is specified we can't actually evaluate any integrals, but we can write them in (possibly) more convenient forms. Let

$$
F(x)=\int\limits_0^x dt \ f(t)
$$

So that $F'(x)=f(x)$. Since $f(x)$ is a pdf defined on $[0,\bar{x}]$, we have $F(0)=0$ and $F(\bar{x})=1$. We can integrate the given expression by parts

$$
\int\limits_0^\bar{x}dx \ x \ln(x)f(x)= \int\limits_0^\bar{x}dx \ x \ln(x)F'(x)
$$

$$
=\bigg[x \ln(x) F(x) \bigg]_0^\bar{x}-\int\limits_0^\bar{x}dx \ (x \ln x)'F(x)
$$

$$
=\bar{x}\ln(\bar{x})F(\bar{x})-\left[ \lim_{x\to 0}x \ln(x)F(x)\right]-\int\limits_0^\bar{x}dx \ (1+\ln x)F(x)
$$

The limit is zero because $x\ln x \to 0$ and $F(x)\to 0$ as $x \to 0$ and . Using $F(\bar{x})=1$ in the boundary term simplifies things to

$$
\int\limits_0^\bar{x}dx \ x \ln(x)f(x)=\bar{x}\ln\bar{x}-\int\limits_0^\bar{x}dx \ (1+\ln x)F(x)
$$